# How to log method calls using spring annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I am trying to log every method call. I am using spring annotations to create the beans instead of the normal xml file. I was wondering how to do this? I have already created the aspect logger and I tried using the tag @Aspect and @Component then scan for it and it still does not log the method calls.

The current aspect logger worked with the spring.xml file.

Here is the aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspectService extends TestSetup
{
    String infoFolderPath = null;

    @Around("execution(* com.quality.pages..*(..))")
    public Object stepLoggerAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        String message = composeMessage(proceedingJoinPoint);

        logger.step(message);

        Object value = null;
        try
        {
            value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            logger.warn(message + " did not finish!");
            storeFailedTestInfo(proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            throw e;
        }

        return value;
    }

    // more methods
}
```

Comment: Please show the (a) class  of which you want to log the method calls. Also, please show your aspect.

Comment: I want to log every method in all the classes that have beans

Comment: It seems that your LoggingAspectService @Component is not being found by the Spring scanner. Make sure this classe is in a package that is target to be component scanned.

Comment: Please edit your question to be an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). More specifically, for AOP-related questions always the full aspect and at least one target application code class are needed (including package names and imports). While for AspectJ this would suffice, for Spring AOP we also need to see your configuration. Please show your working XML configuration as well as your non-working annotation-based one. Mentioning "spring.xml works, annotation-based configuration does not" is not helpful if nobody can see the actual configurations.